# anaconda version and my installed python version

Tags: python, anaconda

Hello every on I have python 3.7.5 on my pc and normally when I run python in cmd I get python 3.7.5 version but after I install anaconda last version and when I check the python version in the in the cmd by typing python I get python 3.7.4 as following :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

my question is how I make python version 3.7.5 a default version in anaconda

Comment: Have you followed [those steps](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)?

Comment: the same steps but the different that I check the box that's add anaconda to  path variable

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda is a bundled distribution of python, your PATH was most likely updated when installing it and is now pointing to the Python bundled with Anaconda instead of the one on your system.

**You can change the path or update the Python bundled with Anaconda.**

Anaconda comes with the `conda` CLI tool, you can use this tool to install the specific version of python you want like so:

```
conda install python=3.5.0
```

Note: conda supports the latest version of Python, consider upgrading!

Comment: All versions of the Anaconda distribution (including miniconda) have the `conda` tool.

Comment: can I do this without running   $$ conda install python=3.7.5

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is a really nice tool for trouble-free management of Python environments.

Additionally if you don't want to use an additional tool, check your path to see which version it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that what has happened here is that Anaconda's base python has been set as the system python, I believe this is an option in the installer for Anaconda. If you really want to use the version of python that you installed then you could try reinstalling with that option off.

However, I would say that since Anaconda is an environment manager, you should very rarely use the root environment anyway. Instead you should create environments based on what you want to do at the time and specify what version of python you want to use.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you have conda and want to use a particular version of Python, create a new environment specifying that version.

Comment: no I want to use the base env. of anaconda with python 3.7.5 as default

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for my is to uninstall anaconda  and try to work without it because the only answer I got is running `conda install python=3.7.5` and that's may take very long time thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

I just try :

```
conda install python=3.7.5 anaconda=custom
```

and it's work fine but when I reinstall anaconda I get the same problem also I get 
[image]

when I check the anaconda python version in control panel home Programs and Features still I get python 3.7.4 as default